# PHP script not showing that you're logged in

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning PHP, and I'm busy with this tutorial over here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kebwxI1Bw88
I did everything according to the video and went over it 3 times, but my script isn't working... and I was wondering if anyone can help me figure out why? My code seems to be exactly like the guy's code on the video.

The video is about creating the login functionality for a forum. What happens with my script is.... It does what it's supposed to when I type in the WRONG user/pass combination (showing the message that it's supposed to show). But, when I type in the RIGHT user/pass combination... The file redirects to the index like it's supposed to... but it's still displaying the login form and not showing the "You are logged in as _ " message.

My Login Form on the index page:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
echo "<form action='login_parse.php' method='post'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username' />
Password: <input type='password' name='password' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Log In'>
";
} else {
echo "<p>You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['username']." $bull; <a href='logout_parse.php'>Logout</a>";
}
```

My login_parse.php file:

```
session_start();
include_once("connect.php");
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit ();
} else {
    echo "Invalid login information. Please return to the previous page. ";
    exit ();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if $_SESSION['uid'] has a value.

print_r($_SESSION);

to see all the values